# Inverted surround channels

Tags: pulseaudio, services, hdmi, speakers

I'm encountering an issue with surround sound on Ubuntu 11.04.
I managed to play sound trough HDMI but the channels are inverted.
For example when Pulse Audio plays on the center speaker, it goes through my LFE. Same thing on the speaker test included in the sound preferences channel.

While searching topics about this issue I tried editing /etc/pulse/daemon.conf by changing the channel-map setting - to no avail. Maybe I didnt use it correctly ?

Any idea to swap those channels and have my 5.1 working correctly?

```
System specs :
Ubuntu 11.04
AsRock aion330
HDMI amp
```

Thanks in advance!

---

`aplay -L` gives this result:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
pulse
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
front:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, VT1708S Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

gnome-volume-control is indeed set to Digital Surround 5.1 HDMI Output. The speaker test is affected by the channels issue, though.

Answer (score 2):

To set up the correct mapping in HDMI 5.1 sound when the channels are configured incorrectly you should try the following in the command line

1. `pulseaudio -k`
2. `gksu gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf`
3. Find the HDMI-surround section there in that file. Switch the incorrect speakers in *channel-mapping* and save the file.
4. Run `speaker-test -c6 -twav`
5. If it is still incorrect, go back to step 1.

Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 with an NVIDIA ION (zotac motherboard).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowlegde on your present ALSA and PulseAudio settings we can only guess what might be wrong here.

To troubleshoot sound output please

- check if ALSA mapping is correct (by invoking `aplay -L` in a terminal)
- make sure your hardware profile is set to 5.1. in gnome-volume-control *Audio Settings -> Hardware*
- try to change remixing settings in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to:

  `enable-remixing = yes` try also with `no`

  `enable-lfe-remixing = no` try also with `yes`

Channel mapping in `daemon.conf` are only working in case there is **no other** channel map present (see also [pulseaudio ticket #825](http://pulseaudio.org/ticket/825)).

ALSA HDMI sound output may be digital and thus - unlike analog channels - mixing for 5.1. surround output is done by the hardware attached.

Comment: hey  thanks for the answer I edited my first post.  For the edits in daemon.conf, stupid question but : shall i un-comment first ? everything seems commented in the file and begins with a ; ...
shall i try enable-remixing = yes AND enable-lfe-remixing = yes at the same time ?

Thanks for the explanation about channel mapping.

I must admit I still dont understand how pulseaudio and alsa work : I mean for example, when I change the settings in sound prefere'nces through Gnome, am I overriding settings such as "default-sample-channels" in daemon.conf ? (which is set at 2 currently)

Comment: I was just guessing if settings may help you here. You may find out by trial and error. **Make a backup of the original custom.cońf to restore later**. Yes, lines need uncommenting by removing `;`. Try all combinations `yes` and `no` and restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k`. GNOME/ALSA settings and PulseAudio settings don't play consistently but as for mixing ALSA/GNOME *should* override settings from daemon.conf. Try it out, you can always restore your backup to default settings. HDMI sound is digital, i.e. **not mixed** in your case. 5.1. mixing is done to analog output only.

Answer (score 0):

@Takkat :
NVM I Found the solution.

I tried your suggestions to no avail... Then I searched for more info on conf files for cards. In the end I ended up looking at presets files loaded by pulseaudio, found out there was an Nvidia profile loaded from nvidia.conf.

I found many hdmi surround 5.1 presets in this nvidia.conf file.

Inverted some channels (eg lfe and front left), saved the file, killed pulseaudio, worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remap the channels of my analog card like this

```
cp /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf ~/.pulse/rotatedProfile.conf
```

I edited that file so that the channel map for my configuration is as I wanted

```
[Mapping analog-surround-51]
device-strings = surround51:%f
channel-map = front-right,rear-right,front-left,rear-left,front-center,lfe
paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker analog-output-desktop-speaker   analog-output-lfe-on-mono
priority = 8
direction = output
```

then I had to force pulseaudio to load the alsa card by hand, not automatically, and set the profile to the file I just created. I don't know if there is a way to force a profile to autodetected cards, or force only one card to be manually detected. I commented out `#load-module module-udev-detect` and `#load-module module-detect` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and added the following line to the end of the file

```
load-module module-alsa-card device_id=Intel profile_set=/home/silent/.pulse/rotatedProfile.conf
```

where `device_id` can be either a number or string. You can see your card names and id's by doing

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

for reference, my output was like this

```
  0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                       HDA Intel at 0xf9ff8000 irq 44
```

so `device_id=0` worked as well as `device_id=Intel`

I have seen reports of numeric id's switching places after reboot so if you don't have different cards with the same name I would go for the string representation.

Edit: in 13.04 modifying `extra-hdmi.conf` instead of `default.conf` without messing with `default.pa` did the trick. On the other hand this has the risk (does it?) of being overwritten during an upgrade.